# How can I test a Samsung Smart TV app on my computer from an external server?

Tags: eclipse, sdk, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I'm trying to bug test a Samsung Smart TV app on my computer (OSX 10.10) that is on an external server. I have Eclipse, Virtual Box, and the emulator installed.

Where should I put the server address to access the app?

Answer (score 2):

Samsung SmartTV Apps are packaged zip files and served through http servers. After downloading the app with your browser you can import the app in eclipse or upload it to your tv/the emulator with an webserver (e.g apache/mamp).

See https://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00012/index.html for how to test/debug smart tv apps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have been given a server address that I am pretty sure is the location of the packaged app...can I run it straight from that address, or do I need to figure out how to download it first?